# Appium getText() for iOS native app automation issue

Tags: appium-ios

I am currently trying to fetch text of an element using .getText() in Appium for an iOS app test scenario. I am trying to fetch this element via Label(also tried Identifier) but somehow this method fetches the text of the Label(or Identifier) instead of the value itself. For example, if Label is 'BSB' and its value is "123-456" :

PageObject Payment:

@iOSFindBy(id = "BSB")

public MobileElement bsbNo;

TestScript :

String bsbValue = Payment.bsbNo.getText();

Assert.assertEquals(bsbValue, "123-456", "BSB Mismatch")

The above code fails at the assertion. So could you pls help me any alternate solution? This seems to be a bug in Xcode. I tried setting accessibilityLabel, accessibilityIdentifier or even trying to get Attribute of bsbNo (bsbNo.getAttribute("value")) BUT nothing worked.

Kindly help!
thanks

Comment: Run `driver.getPageSource()` and print output to console. Then add that XML to your question. Currently there not enough details about your issue

Comment: Hi,  Now getting value is not supported, better use accessibility identifier for element Id and set the value to accessibility Label in app code . Then use getText(), this will get the label value.

Comment: @arulchristopher , yea mate thats what we did and it helped! Thanks